# Android - Are there any conflicts with inflating the toolbar menu, and using the supportActionBar which inflates the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu?

Tags: android

I'm using a library, which requires the toolbar menu to be inflated like this

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
```

My app is using the support action bar though

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And I'm inflating the menu in onCreateOptionMenu

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

I've tried inflating the toolbar with the menu, and using the support actionbar, while inflating in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and everything appears to work, although I'm concerned about some unknown consequence of doing so.

Is there any problems with inflating the menu in the toolbar, as well as calling `getMenuInflater` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any issue with that, in both cases you are using Action Bar. The difference is in first case you are using the Toolbar with the reference of Action Bar by assigning your Toolbar to Action Bar, but you are still using Action Bar. So, there isn't anything to worry.
Maybe it is confusing for you, but don't worry it's fine. If you still want to clarify then read about both Action Bar and Toolbar on Google Developers Website. Read about them thoroughly like what they actually, I hope it will clarify all your confusions.